# AttributeError: '' object has no attribute 'velx'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying my hand at pygame, this is what I've got so far. It bites me with the error "AttributeError: 'Pokemon' object has no attribute 'velx'", and I can't figure out why. The traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/GameDev/Main.py", line 37, in <module>
    pokemon.motion()
  File "C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/GameDev\classes.py", line 31, in motion
    self.rect.x += self.velx
AttributeError: 'Pokemon' object has no attribute 'velx'
```

Pokemon is my sprite, by the way. My Main code:

```
import pygame,sys
from classes import *

pygame.init()
WIDTH,HEIGHT = 640, 360
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT),0,32)
img_pokemon = pygame.image.load("pokemon.png")

#colours
clr1 = (22,122,211)
clr2 = (0,44,166)
clr3 = (34,55,245)
clrvar = 1
spritemovex = 1
spritemovey = 1

#clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 24
fivesecondinterval = FPS * 5
totalframes = 0

pokemon = Pokemon(0, 100, 40, 30, "pokemon.png")

while True:
    #processes
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(FPS)

    #logic
    pokemon.motion()

    totalframes += 1
    clrvar +=3
    if clrvar > 255:
        clrvar = 1

    spritemovex += 2
    spritemovey += 2
    if spritemovex > WIDTH:
        spritemovex %= WIDTH
    if spritemovey > HEIGHT:
        spritemovey %= HEIGHT
    #draw
    screen.fill( (90,clrvar,180) )
    screen.blit(img_pokemon, (spritemovex,spritemovey))
```

My Classes code:

```
import pygame

class BaseClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        BaseClass.allsprites.add(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_string)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.width = width
        self.height = height



class Pokemon(BaseClass):
    List = pygame.sprite.Group()
    def __init___(self, x, y, width, height, image_string):

        BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string)
        Pokemon.List.add(self)
        self.velx = 3

    def motion(self):

        self.rect.x += self.velx
```

Comment: Your `__init__` method in `Pokemon` has an extra `_` on the right side, `__init___`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled `__init__`:

```
def __init___(self, x, y, width, height, image_string):
#         123
```

Python won't call that method. Remove that third underscore:

```
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string):
```